# Django+Celery in Heroku not executing async task

Tags: django, heroku, celery, django-celery

I have Django+Celery in Heroku, and Celery is set up as:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = "django://"  # tell kombu to use the Django database as the message queue
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'
```

I have 2 tasks defined in `tasks.py`, one periodic and another that is executed on asynchronous calls:

```
@task
def test_one_shot():
    print "One shot"

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(minute="*/5"))
def test_periodic():
    print "Periodic"
```

Heroku is configured with a main web worker and a auxiliar worker:

```
web: gunicorn config.wsgi:application ON
worker: python manage.py celery worker -B -l info ON
```

With this setup, I run the `test_one_shot` task as follows:

```
test_one_shot.apply_async(eta=datetime.now()+timedelta(minutes=2))
```

And although it appears as registered in the heroku logs:

```
Received task: test.tasks.test_one_shot[f29c609d-b6e8-45d4-808d-2ca690f029af] eta:[2016-08-07 00:09:30.262362+02:00]
```

It never executes. On the other hand, the periodic task `test_periodic` is executed as expected. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT: The task was executed was not appearing in the logs due a datetime time aware issue. However when the task is programmatically called, it is never executed.

Comment: you need to debug it. may be you are getting an error inside the task and it wouldnt show errors on async tasks.

Comment: @levi How would you debug it? I am already testing a function which is only a print statement and looking directly to the heroku logs of the celery worker (where nothing appears).

Comment: here is the way to debug a celery task 
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/tutorials/debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

I end up changing the celery backend to use RabbitMQ in Heroku following [this guide](https://drdaeman.github.io/heroku-djcelery-example/), and the problem get solved.

Basically, I installed RabbitMQ on Heroku:

```
$ heroku addons:add cloudamqp
```

And set the new configuration for it:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Madrid'

BROKER_URL = env("CLOUDAMQP_URL", default="django://")
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 1
BROKER_CONNECTION_MAX_RETRIES = None

CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["json", "msgpack"]
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = 'djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler'
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = False

if BROKER_URL == "django://":
    INSTALLED_APPS += ("kombu.transport.django",)
```